# Biztalk drops duplicate files in destination folder

Tags: biztalk

I have an IN folder and an OUT folder. I have Receive Location with XMLReceive pipeline set. and Send Port with Pass through Transmit Pipeline set. Between these two (receive and send) ports I am calling a web service with custom piplines (both send and receive).

Problem is when I drop a file in IN folder I am receiving two files in OUT folder,

- 1st one is the same which I dropped in IN folder.
- 2nd one is the required resultant file.

My Question is why I am getting original file again. Where I am doing wrong? Please help

Regards,

Comment: Do you have any filters defined on your file send port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your send port filters and [subscriptions](http://geekswithblogs.net/sthomas/archive/2005/10/03/55872.aspx), then adjust your filters.

Comment: thanks for reply. Actually I am new to Biztalk. I checked my subscription for send port, it contained another property SPTransportID, I coppied its value and pasted in my send port filter. I worked fine. It solved the problem but another question arise that. Do I have to check for subscription for all send port every time when I make a send port?